# What does Microsoft.Common.props do

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

I noticed that when I create a project using Class Library template the .csproj contains import of Microsoft.Common.props

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

However when I create a project using Unit Test Project template it is not present.

So what does Microsoft.Common.props do? How does it benefit the project?

Comment: just view it as a dependency and forget it?

Comment: I could or I choose not to and get smarter :P

Comment: pretty sad when people are voting to close this for being too broad.

Comment: is the unit test project a mstest project?

Comment: @KeithNicholas If we are talking about type by <ProjectTypeGuids> content than yes, it is {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB} but I use xUnit anyway, why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979250/what-should-i-install-except-visual-studio-itself-for-microsoft-common-props-t

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It does a lot of things and brings in a part of the build logic.

In fact, there are two important imports for "standard" .NET projects: `Microsoft.Common.props` and `Microsoft.Common.targets` (latter one may be implicitly included from a project type specific import file).

The basic idea is to split build logic into two parts, one that is imported before your project's contents (which will be the `.props`) and one that is included afterwards (`.targets`).

The `Microsoft.Common.props` will define some properties based on conventions - e.g. set defaults for the current configuration (e.g. build for `Debug` if no configuration was specified when building from the command line).

It also imports other files installed as extensions to the msbuild/vs tools installation or the project - e.g. NuGet 4+ makes uses of this for `PackageReference` style projects.

Once the `Microsoft.Common.props` import has set up all the defaults, it is your project's turn to change the defaults according to user choices (and project templates) as well as define some other properties and items needed for the build process.

Your project must then import a `.targets` file that defines the msbuild logic needed to perform a build of the project. This is done through `Microsoft.Common.targets` (and the files it chooses to import).
Anything that needs to override logic coming from this file needs to be specified after this import - this is why VS' project templates have a commented out area for custom `AfterBuild` targets. Since `AfterBuild` is already defined via the common targets, you will need to override it after this import (or use a custom name and add `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"` which is preferred in newer MSBuild versions).

The `.props`/`.targets` split for defaults and logic is also used a lot in custom build extensions and a naming convention for msbuild files that should be imported at the top (`.props`) and the bottom (`.targets`) of projects.

In "SDK-based" projects which have been introduced for .NET Core but can also be used with .NET Framework, this concept is expanded upon by importing `Sdk.props` and `Sdk.targets` files - before and after the project contents respectively. A set of convention helps locating these files and even allows you to omit `<Import>` elements by specifying an attribute on the project file: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">...</Project>`. These imports will define even more defaults than `Microsoft.Common.props`, allowing for very small and more human readable project files. (currently, only .NET Core / .NET Standard and ASP.NET Core project templates use this format since VS 2017 uses a different project system for it than for classic csproj files)

Comment: Your explanation was very clear and helped me resolve a build issue

Comment: "different project system" - you are talking about the obsolete xproj, do you?

Comment: No, VS 2017 has the "classic" csproj.dll/msvbproj.dll and a new "CPS"-based project system which is open source. See https://github.com/dotnet/project-system for the new project system.