# What should I install, except Visual Studio itself, for Microsoft.Common.props to appear under c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

My csproj files import Microsoft.Common.props, but this file does not exist on my build server.

The build server does not have Visual Studio 2015 installed (and I like it this way), but we did install the 2015 build tool chain. The file is not there.

What else is missing to install? Google seems to be helpless here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I install, except Visual Studio itself, for Microsoft.Common.props to appear under c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\?

AFAIK, you have to install the Visual Studio 2015, if you need the import file `Microsoft.Common.props`. Or you can just copy this file from the machine which have installed the Visual Studio 2015.

If you do not want to install the Visual Studio 2015 on your build server, I would like suggest you can upgrade your project to Visual Studio 2017, then you can use the [Visual Studio Installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=button%20cta&utm_content=download%20vs2017), which you can see new experience:

[image]

The smallest install is just a few hundred megabytes, yet still contains basic code editing support for more than twenty languages including source code control. Most users will want to install more. You can add one or more 'workloads' that represent common frameworks, languages, and platforms instead of entire Visual Studio.

Check more info [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0#--visual-studio-2017-version-150-2622804-1).